# Unpaired value in UriTemplate works on one computer, but not another

Tags: .net, wcf

In my web service I have to recieve HTTP request over a URI of the form */a?b*:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "http://hostname/.../a?b")]
Stream MethodName(Stream stream);
```

without the typical *?b=c*.

This works fine on my development computer, running Windows Vista and .NET 3.5 SP1 (and adding URLACLs). However when attempting to host this op on a machine with Windows Server 2003 (.NET 3.5 w/ no SP), I get an InvalidOperationException telling me the URI template is not valid and that each portion of the query string must be of the form 'name=value'. If absolutely necessary, the client program can be changed to match a more compatible URI, but are there any remedies or work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing 3.5 SP1 on your windows server machine. SP1 has new functionality not just bug fixes.

Comment: That did the trick, it seems. Do you have any references to a complete change list? I'm unable to locate one on my own.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't provide much specific details (like any other pages I found).